# Video with 50 FPS slightly off

Tags: video, frame-rate

I created a video and exported it in MPEG4 format with H264 encoder and 50 FPS.

When I import this file to Camtasia 2020 into a project with 50 FPS I notice a stuttering in the video. When I go frame by frame I can see that Camtasia is doubling some frames. Increasing the FPS to 50.95 in Blender makes the playback better, but still not perfect.
The file information (right click, properties) shows the exact same frame rate I set in Blender.

Now I am wondering if that is a Blender or Camtasia problem and how to fix it.

Can someone help?

Thanks and best regards,
Michael

Answer (score -1):

It is most probably a problem with blender. You shouldn't have set it to 50 FPS though. You should have gone with 60 FPS. If you still need it in 50 fps, I would say you should render it in frame-by-frame form and then import it to Camtasia 2020 and arrange it in the order you want. Make each frame last 0.02 seconds. Then see, it will probably work. If it still feels a bit rough, you can smoothen it using the tool you have. I am not very sure though, this is my best guess. If you face any issues, please comment. Hope the answer helps.

Comment: I have to work with 50 FPS, cause I am combining video files and the camera files are 50 FPS.
I will try to work with the individual .png pictures. This is the way I render animations anyhow.

Comment: well, go ahead and try it in the png format. How long is the video though ? If you tell me that, I would be able to help much better.

Comment: The video is 450 frames or 9 seconds. The import and use of the individual .png files in Camtasia is possible, but it floats the media area since every single picture is considered one media file. Oh, and loading the project takes forever...

Comment: But honestly I think this is more likely a Camtasia problem. The video file that Blender creates plays just fine in a stand alone video player. It only stutters when imported into Camtasia.

Comment: I seriously don't know much about Camtasia but I seriously don't think it is a Camtasia problem. But, as I said, I don't know much about Camtasia, so could be it can't handle 50 FPS. As for the media problem, I don't know. Can you try switching to some other software, kdenlive. It's free. I think it should work there. As for repeating frames, can't you delete the frames where it stutters?

Comment: Camtasia Support just confirmed, that is only works with 30 or 60 FPS and not with 50.
I guess I have to adopt to 60 FPS then... :-(
There are workarounds like Aster17 suggested: manually deleting frames. But that also shortens the time of the clip. I hope the films from the video camera look ok when transformed from 50 to 60 FPS. Anyway, thank you all for your help!

Comment: well, you could use Kdenlive. It's free and is as good as adobe premiere.

Comment: hm.. ok. Will try! Thanks!

Comment: please do, it is open source and works with any windows version that is windows 7 and above. It also works with mac and Linux. Here's the link: 
https://kdenlive.org/en/
If it helps, please tell me, I want to use it in my future projects too. Or you could directly render it in blender as video and then use it's video editor, but it isn't as good as kdenlive and takes a long time.

Comment: Kdenlive works very well. Importing 50 FPS is no problem and I can import MPEG 4 with lossless quality (which Camtasia does not support anymore) and also I can use the Matroska container (which Camtasia does not support). Kdenlive supports exporting in H.265 (which Camtasia does not support). A lot of advantages. But the handling is different (of course) and it takes a while to find all the "How to do"s that I know well in Camtasia. But I will continue with Kdenlive and see what the downfalls are (if any). Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks you. I am happy my answer helped you. Would you mind upvoting my answer.

Comment: I would, but I see no option to vote. Maybe I need a higher reputation score before I am allowed to vote?

Comment: Do you see the arrow on top of the -1? Click on that and it will upvote. It won't show but I will still get the upvote.